# Is Sony Xperia EC1504 supported for Android app development?

Tags: android, sony-xperia

I am planning to buy a new phone so that I can deploy my Android apps to that phone. I want to buy Sony Xperia EC1504. However I am unable to find the driver for that phone in:  http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/
Does it mean I do not need to install a SONY driver on my pc at all, or that Sony phone simply cannot be used for Android development? Thank you.

Comment: if your system is connected with internet,  then it will automatically download the driver(at the time when you connect the device). else you have to download it and install.

Comment: @Signare According to the official Android Development web site, I have to download the driver from a phone manufacturer. http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html  It seems that driver will not be downloaded automatically from internet. According to the web site, I have to download the driver manually because I use Windows. If I use a Mac, it will not be a problem.

Comment: when you connect your phone, windows will automatically download the driver.